# What is the Most simple way to store image in Data base in MVC

Tags: wordpress, forms, asp.net-mvc-4

ok, So criticism apart, I'm New to MVC, my Point is how can i store an image in data base that will be uploaded by user.

i'm Creating a simple blog via MVC And what i Want is A form Same like WordPress "ADD NEW POST". Where user can enter title,TAGS,Headings, But What my Part is, I have to store all of them in DB. i can Do the CSS part, but i'm struck in Functionality that will be Getting all values From user (view) And Then Storing it in database also Displaying it.

below is my google-d Code for View in MVC.

```html
@model SimpleBlogg.Models.PostContent
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "AddContentToDB";
}

<div class="UploadPicForm" style="margin-top:20px;">
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddContentToDB", "AddNewPost", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input type="file" name="ImageData" id="ImageData" onchange="fileCheck(this);" />
}
</div>
```

Comment: I suggest you read about basic asp-net mvc concepts/tutorials including form submits and model binding before trying to build anything. Regarding saving image, you can store that in disk or store that as byte array in your db table. None is going to write entire code for you. you should try something yourself and when you run into a specific problem ask a question with very specific details and relevant code. Thanks

Comment: thanks For motivational lines... i'm Trying my best into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save as Base64 string:

```
static string base64String = null;  
public string ImageToBase64()   
{  
    string path = "D:\\SampleImage.jpg";  
    using(System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(path))  
    {  
        using(MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())  
        {  
            image.Save(m, image.RawFormat);  
            byte[] imageBytes = m.ToArray();  
            base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);  
            return base64String;  
        }  
    }  
}  
public System.Drawing.Image Base64ToImage()   
{  
    byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);  
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);  
    ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);  
    System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms, true);  
    return image;  
}  
protected void ImageToBase_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)   
{  
    TextBox1.Text = ImageToBase64();  
}  
protected void BaseToImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{  
    Base64ToImage().Save(Server.MapPath("~/Images/Hello.jpg"));  
    Image1.ImageUrl = "~/Images/Hello.jpg";  
}
```

source: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/convert-an-image-to-base64-string-and-base64-string-to-image